# I cannot seem to be able to target the navbar-brand element in CSS after adding link_to in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, css-selectors

After swapping the nav link to link_to in rails , I cannot target the navbar-brand in css anymore . 
what am I doing wrong ?

I have tried putting it into a div and give it an id but no success

Adding an id in rails like I did for the About link will target the navbar-brand but then it moves the logo and the navbar-brand to the top of the navbar with no border or padding at the top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Saasapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class='container'>
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="navbar-brand">
              <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-group"></i>DevMatch
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><%= link_to "About" , about_path, {id: 'about' } %></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Also this is the CSS in question , I am trying to change the color of the navbar-brand and logo:

```
//Background gradient
.home-callout, .navbar {
        background: #5433FF;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #A5FECB, #20BDFF, #5433FF);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #A5FECB, #20BDFF, #5433FF); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

// Home-page Styles
.home-callout {
    color: #00264d;
   margin-top: -20px;
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 100px;
}

//Nav Styles

* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    border: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {

    color: #661aff;
    &:hover{
        opacity: 0.75;
    }

}

#about {

    color: #99ffff;
    &:hover{
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
}

@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';

//Typography Styles
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

@import 'font-awesome-sprockets';
@import 'font-awesome';
```

Comment: Maybe add to your question (1) the `CSS` in question, and (2) the rendered `html` (instead of the `.erb`).

Comment: The selector for `navbar-brand` would be preceded by `#` not `.` the dot notation is for class and the pound notation is for element by id. Also you are importing bootstrap after your css changes so this could be an issue if bootstrap already defines rules for any element you intend to change. css rules will be overridden by the lower rules or rules that are more specific.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have changed the . dot notation with # for navbar-brand . still nothing . and if bootstrap defines rules for color and position , how can I change those ? Thank you

Comment: @Marius.T what are you intending to change the color of? if you want to change the icon color then the selector would be more like `#navbar-brand i {color: #661aff;}` if you want to change the background then `#navbar-brand {background-color: #661aff;}` it is unclear what you intend to do here

Comment: @engineersmnky  I am trying to change the color of navbar-brand which is DevMatch .... using ' #navbar-brand i {color: #661aff;} ' changes the color of the icon alone . That's good but the color of my navbar-brand won't change from default even after i target it with ' #navbar-brand {color: #661aff;} ' .

Comment: Okay now I see you have `#navbar-brand` and `.navbar-brand` in that case refer to my first comment where you are importing bootstrap after your css changes and boostrap is overriding your changes. move the imports to the top of the file or using a very specific selector like `#navbar-brand a.navbar-brand {color: #661aff;}`

Comment: @engineersmnky Wow that finally worked  . I used #navbar-brand a.navbar-brand  selector . Thank you so much , but how could I have found out that specificity of a.navbar-brand ?

Comment: So your issue is that bootstrap has styling for `.navbar-brand` so when you style it then import bootstrap below it bootstrap wins. As mentioned CSS rules apply top down and by specificity so in this case your selector is more specific than bootstrap and thus you win the selector is find the id `navbar-brand` (`#navbar-brand`) then find the decendent anchor tags with the class navbar-brand (`a.navbar-brand`) and stylize them. This selection is extremely specific thus your styling applies. Easiest solution in the future is to import bootstrap first

Comment: Valuable and very much appreciated information . Many thanks